# Limit gives wrong answer on both Mathematica and Wolfram-Alpha

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

[My Input and Output on Mathematica 12.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3s19.jpg)

```
Limit[(Cos[x^2]/(x^2) - Cos[(x + 1)^2]/((x + 1)^2))/(1/(x^3)), x -> Infinity]

Plot[(Cos[x^2]/(x^2) - Cos[(x + 1)^2]/((x + 1)^2))/(1/(x^3)), {x, 0, 1000}]
```

The two results in this image are contradictory.According to the plot,the function is divergent,while the limit goes zero.

Clearly,the answer of the limit is not correct.

It seems that my problem may not appear on someone else's computer.My version is 12.0.0.0,and according to the comments,there is no problem on version 12.2

However,what astonished me most is that Wolfram-Alpha gives the same wrong answer.

[The result on Wolfram-Alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmFAh.jpg)

What's wrong with this?Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This question probably better on the Mathematica site because it seems to deal with quirks of Mathematica itself.  Here's a similar question, albeit on an older version of Mathematica: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89054/why-doesnt-mathematica-evaluate-this-simple-limit/159278

Comment: ../ (1 / x^3) == ..*x^3 ?

Comment: So this now immediately fails for 13.0, returns unevaluated.